# Inconsistent display caused by element rotation and transform-style: preserve-3d

Tags: css, css-transforms

I did some experiments today and found that the problem boils down to the `transform: rotateY(180deg)` and container rotation with `transform-style: preserve-3d`. I will depict the details again. The original question is below which you can simply ignore it.

This time, I will enable `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on `section` from the beginning which can eliminate some unrelated details.

The code:

```css
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    /*adjust deg here*/
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
img,div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
div {
    width: 267px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <img src="http://www.weekends.net.cn/assets/img/blur.jpg">
    <div id="back">abc</div>
</section>
```

Please increase the rotation degree of section tag up to `180deg`. Then the div will disappear. Don't stop and keep on increasing, the div will alternately appear and disappear, which causes inconsistency and unpredictability. What's worse is that the width of `div` will affect this 'inconsistency'. For example, after the argument of rotateY() set to 180deg, reduce the width of `div` by 1 pixel, and `div` will appear! That's the problem I found. Is it a bug of browser? I tested this on chrome on Mac.

**Original question:**
I am reading chapter 8 of CSS: The Definitive Guide 4th Edition which is related to this problem.

What I want to do:
There is one section tag on the page which contains one `div` and one `img` tag. `img` represents the front side while `div` represents the back side. When the card faces front, users can only see the `img`. When the card faces back(by hover), users can see `div` and `img`'s back side through transparent background of `div`.

My code is:

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

img,
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

section:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="http://www.weekends.net.cn/assets/img/blur.jpg">
  <div id="back">abc</div>
</section>
```

As you can see, `div` only covers only part of the `img` if you hover onto it. If I increase the width of `div` up to 267px, then the `div` will 'disappear'. In fact, after some experiments, the `div` will disappear after its width reach 2/3 of the width of `section`. I think the problem maybe related to rotate, but I can not figure it out. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: I have converted your code to a snippet. However, it seems to work pretty well, I have increased also the width, but I can't see any problem whatsoever

Comment: @vals toggle the hover of the `section` on and increase the width of `div` over 267px, then you should be able to see the problem. I tested this both on chrome 56.0.2924.87(64-bit) and safari on Mac. `div` disappeared with hover.

Answer (score 2):

I still can't see the problem in my tests. But the problem that you describe could be a z-fighting issue. [z-fight explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). If this is the case, you can solve it putting the div slightly in front of the section:

```css
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transition: transform 5s;
}
img,div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
div {
    width: 267px;
    height: 300px;
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px); /* added the z translation */
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.6);
}

section:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<section>
    <img src="http://www.weekends.net.cn/assets/img/blur.jpg">
    <div id="back">abc</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the backside visible when "turned to the front" both elements (img and div#back) need to have `backface-visibility: hidden`. But this doesn't work with any transparency.

We can however cheat a bit by adding a flipped background to the backside with a pseudo element.

https://jsfiddle.net/oynpktxd/

```
div:before {
   background-image: url("http://www.weekends.net.cn/assets/img/blur.jpg");
   content: "";
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
   z-index: -1;
   opacity: 0.4;
}
```